# How to install scikit-learn-0.14.1 with atlas at non-standard location

Tags: scikit-learn

In Ubuntu 12.04 under python 2.7.3 I am
trying to install scikit-learn-0.14.1 using the
"test the package before installing". The first step
(python setup.py build_ext --inplace) since to finish OK
See the output at [  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7043418 ]

The testing step, however (nosetests sklearn/), things are not so nice.
It ended with 22 errors and 9 tests failed. 
See the output at  [ https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7044411 ]

If I am right, the problem since to be related to the atlas library.
I am using my own build of the libraries blas-lapack-atlas, the 
directory at which they are installed (/home/myacct/myProg/NumLibs64b/lib) 
is listed at the 
beginning of the building process. However,  no where the compiling options
of gcc/g++ includes  -llapack -lcblas -lf77blas -latlas
Only a mention of '-DNO_ATLAS_INFO=-1 is listed during the building process.
Does this option means not to use atlas?

Numpy and Scipy were build successfully using the same 
blas-lapack-atlas libraries (via the corresponding STATIC versions).

So I guess the question is how to modify setup.py of  scikit-learn-0.14.1
in order to  build it using
a non-standard location for the STATIC libraries blas-lapack-atlas?

Regards,

Sergio

Comment: AFAIK, scikit-learn is using the following info to locate BLAS / LAPACK to build against:

`from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info; print(get_info('blas_opt'))`

What does it ouput in your case?

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 30 2013, 13:55:58) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info
>>> print(get_info('blas_opt'))
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
{'libraries': ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas'], 'library_dirs': ['/home/myacct/myProg/NumLibs64b/lib'], 'define_macros': [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)], 'language': 'c', 'include_dirs': ['/home/myacct/myProg/NumLibs64b/include']}

Comment: That looks fine. Can you please open a github issue mentioning all the details of your setup and the error messages you get?

Comment: How can I open a "github issue" ? In any case, I did a test being able to compile scikit-learn-0.14.1 with STATIC version of ATLAS using the building command:           

python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs='/home/myacct/myProg/NumLibs64b/include/  -L/home/srojas/myProg/NumLibs64b/lib -llapack -lcblas -lf77blas -latlas' --inplace

Running the test (OUTPUT at [ https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7089302 ] ):
    python nosetests sklearn/  
 ended with
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1860 tests in 137.411s
FAILED (SKIP=14, errors=1, failures=2)

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues